# How the duplication of data come in django and how can I avoid it?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, thread-safety

I am doing a project by django,just a person project.

I try the project by django with celery,and add two task in celery.

one task, is about a spider write by requests,get some proxy ip information and save to mysql by django orm ,which is update_or_create(defaults={'ip':'','port':''},**{'key':'value'}).I keep this task would always control data by one worker through redis lock.such as ,one work run the task,redis lock get and the other work try to get lock failed and would not contorl the data.

the other task,is a spider,write by tornado,which is used to check the proxy ip data. Also, would run by one worker through redis lock. and the spider by tornado is a single thread ,too.

the two task may run at the same time.

### Here comes the problem!

when  I run the project a few time later,about several hours later. I found some data are the same in mysql. The ip,port and some others are the same.

And when the code run to update_or_create() comes the error :

#### *get() return 2.*

How the data come? In my thought,although at most two thread would run together, but one is use updata_or_create,one is use .save() .The task use save() would not born duplication of data?and the update_or_create() would check the data by get(), it means coming None to say no data like this ip and port in database,but ,it has.

Could anyone explain the reason to me ?

Comment: `task` code is need

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I am uploading the code to the github,in the file: comm_tools..py   all the code is in project.[the project link](https://github.com/bigpangl/dj_proxy)

Comment: try get `ProxyData` dynamic,move `data_need = ProxyData.objects.all()` in `put_ip_infor` method like `for each_data in ProxyData.objects.all()`

Comment: I  am trying what you say,it maybe 30 or 60 minutes comes the result. If I put the `data_need = ProxyData.objects.all(0` in `put_ip_infor` like `for each_data in ProxyData.objects.all()`, what different comes? In my eye, I get no different, I means, I do not know why should do like this? I thought the reason about the error comes from the part of spider the proxy ips,not the check part?

Comment: By now, I had get some duplication of data . The data show it was create in different time, in two task(get ip data and save to mysql) head and below. one of which had not checkd.

Comment: The queryset has lazy load feature,if you don't call `.all()` everytime,the queryset may not same with db,call `.all()` will refresh queryset from db.This lazy load feature may the reason cause your bug.

Comment: Now I update the github,Can you check it once more?From the duplication of data,I found that ,the two the same data,comes from a spider,which get ip information and save to database which task use the update_or_create(),because I add `add_time ` in model,and set the `auto_now_add=True`,`change_time` `auto_now=True`,the `add_time`had value.

Comment: please post an example data of `data = args[0]`

Comment: If ip and port is the only two points decide whether create a new instance or not,it should be `ProxyData.objects.update_or_create(ip_address=data.get('ip_address'),ip_port=data.get('ip_port'),defaults=**data)`

Comment: `ProxyData.objects.update_or_create(defaults=default,**data)` mean if an instance fit **data then update it's ip and port.If i'm guess right,this is just the opposite of what you want.

Comment: I will try. And I read the documents again ,foud that , maybe you are right.i use by a wrong way.
 Thanks for your explain.Best wishs~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ip` and `port` are the only two points deciding whether to create a new instance or not, it should be:

```
ProxyData.objects.update_or_create(
    ip_address=data.get('ip_a‌​ddress'),
    ip_port=dat‌​a.get('ip_port'),
    def‌​aults=**data,
)
```

But

```
ProxyData.objects.update_or_create(defaults=default, **data)
```

means that `ip` and `port` values are updated only if instance fields match `**data`. Therefore, if there is no match for `data`, a new entry will be inserted with `default` values, possibly resulting in duplicated data. If I'm guessing right, this is just the opposite of what you want.